# ActiveRecord::Relation issue on acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I am a rails newbie. I am trying to implement acts-as-taggable-on on my sample app. I am able to enter multiple tags using tag_list but facing issues searching them.

This is what I got.

I used scaffold User to generate the controller & model.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :tags

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My User Model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  scope :by_join_date, order("created_at DESC")  
end
```

My User controller

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
    @users = User.all
    @search = User.tagged_with("Tag11")
end
...
...
...
end
```

I also did not make any changes to class ActsAsTaggableOnMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration after installing the gem.

In my view I replaced :tags with :tag_list in my _form, index & show html files

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :tags %><br />
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</div>
```

This is what I get in the browser

[image: view]

Could you please help me understand where I am making a mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with @search in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing (because you haven't provided the code from your other view yet) but:
when you do `@search = User.tagged_with("Tag11")` what is getting returned is not the tag names, but the actual tag objects. If you have:  `<%= @search %>` in your view, it won't work. You'll need something like:

```
<%= @search.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! If I want to lets say click on Tag12.. How to get all the related users who are tagged to Tag12? Join in <%= @search.map(&:name).join(', ') %> works well but is there a way to get them in a list? Thank you..

Comment: They are already an array. If you want a list, just do something like: <ul><% @search.each do |tag|  %><li><%= tag.name %></li><% end %></ul>