# Rails autocomplete with acts-as-taggable-on issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I am a rails newbie. I am trying to implement acts-as-taggable-on with autocomplete. The problem I am facing is if I have multiple tags for a user, autocomplete suggests the entire tag_list instead of a single tag.

This is a follow up question with [ActiveRecord::Relation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575153/activerecordrelation-issue-on-acts-as-taggable-on/8577661#8577661) I faced earlier & solved with help from [Taryn East](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219883/taryn-east).

I want autosuggest to suggest me only Grey & Green Tags instead of Grey, White. I think its suggesting me Grey, White because I created those tags for something else before, so its taking the entire array instead of a single record in an array.

[image]

[image]

How can I overcome this issue & ask it to suggest me only a single tag & no multiple tags?

This is what I got.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :tags %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_users_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <h3><%= user.name %></h3>
 <h4><i><%= user.tag_list %></i> | <%= time_ago_in_words(user.created_at) %> ago</h4>
 <h4><%= link_to 'Show', user %> | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %> | <%= link_to 'Delete', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></h4>
<% end %>

<h1>Listing All Tags [<%= @smart.map(&:name).length %>]</h1>
<ul>
<% @smart.each do |tag| %>
<li> <%= tag.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb is

```
<h1>New user</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  scope :by_join_date, order("created_at DESC")  
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'

def index
    @users = User.all
    @smart = User.tag_counts_on(:tags)
end

def new
    @user = User.new
end
end
```

How can I overcome this issue & ask it to suggest me only a single tag & no multiple tags? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you taking a look at this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields). It pretty much does what you want.

Comment: Thank You on the Railscasts video tip! I saw the video but Ryan was explaining more like using saved Single Tags (Author), one at a time but mine allows to save multiple tags when saving information. I want to display single tags what what matches in the query later instead of showing the entire array saved earlier!